# why do I get "cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment" error when trying to use SherlockListFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have to convert ListFragments to SherlockListFragment in my app.

So while I set up Sherlock correctly (at least it works on my home screen as SherlockActivity) I now just need to use  SherlockListFragment instead of ListFragment.

So all I did is to change my fragemnt from ListFragment to SherlockListFragment:

```
    public class Select_F extends SherlockListFragment { //before it was ListFragment

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  }
...
```

I call it from within the xml: (which I did not modify)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment                             <- this is line 7
        android:id="@+id/f"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.xxx.Screens.Select_F" >
    </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then during inflate I get the cast error.

```
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.Select_screen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:255)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.setContentView(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:119)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity.setContentView(SherlockActivity.java:229)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at com.xxx.xxx.Select_screen.onCreate(Select_screen.java:62)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    ... 11 more

10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.xxx.Screens.Select_F cannot be cast to android.app.Fragment

10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:549)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4235)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:673)
10-12 08:49:07.420: E/AndroidRuntime(15144):    ... 22 more
```

I guess somehow the xml file still wants a Fragment instead of a SherlockListFragment - but why?

What did I miss here?

many thanks!

Comment: The Sherlock fragments are based on the fragments from the compatibility package so they require you to use the `FramentActivity` or a type of `SherlockActivity`.

Comment: Thanks - I totally missed that - please just put your comment as the answer so I can accept it. By the way, is there anywhere a better selection of samples - I could not find one single SherlockListFragment with xml example anywhere...

Comment: I posted an answer. Regarding samples, I guess you already checked the samples that come with the Sherlock library, beside that you can pretty much use any `ListFragment` sample out there as the `SherlockListFragment` will fit quite well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sherlock` fragments are based on the `Fragment` class from the compatibility package(`android.support.v4.app.Fragment`) so they require your activities to extends `FragmentActivity`(also from the compatibility package) or one of the `SherlockActivity` which extends the `FragmentActivity`.